# Why Do Java Buttons use String commands instead of Enums?

Tags: java, string, swing, actionlistener

I'm curious as to why many actionable swing components (Buttons for example) in java use java.lang.String for the setActionCommand(String) method instead of a java.lang.Object?

The latter seems like it would be a much more flexible arrangement.

Comment: You'd have to ask the developers of Swing that question.  The best we can do is guess at why they went that route.

Comment: Probably because Swing pre-dates Java Enums by a number of years.

Comment: Enums exist in Java since version 1.5. Java swing exist since 1.2.

Comment: Additionally to what David said: having the action command as an enum parameter would require that all possible values for the enum are defined somewhere - clearly not very flexible. By using a string, every application can use *anything* for an actioncommand, not just the enums defined by Swing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually if they set it to use the 'java.lang.enum' type, every enum type would be covered.  And by "anything", isn't it limiting it to just Strings?  That's very limiting and is the horrible side effect of encouraging hardcoding string variables into code.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm sure this is the answer.  If you put in as an answer I'll accept it.  I'm surprised they never added an overloaded function for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing has been around, in one form or another, since December 1996.  It became part of J2SE with release 1.2 in December 1998, although it had been available as a separate library since well before that date.

Java Enums were introduced with release 5.0, in September 2004.  So they weren't an option for the developers of Swing.